# element is not able to display over clip path background

Tags: html, css

I want my input field to display half over the gradient background of clip path and half outside it but I am not able to get it. Please help me solve this problem. The input field "Try for free now!" and the text in below div is not completely visible. However I wanted it to display completely and properly by keeping the gradient background as it is.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signUpBtn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(138, 147, 153, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid rgba(80, 110, 133, 0.75);
}

.signUpBtn {
    font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgba(183, 190, 196, 0.75);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(141, 159, 173, 0.75);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tryUpBtn {
    font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: rgba(183, 190, 196, 0.75);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(141, 159, 173, 0.75);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: rgba(194, 194, 193, 0.308);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.tryUpBtn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(138, 147, 153, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid rgba(80, 110, 133, 0.75);
}

.gradientSec {
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(57deg, rgb(245, 31, 209), rgb(49, 47, 199));
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 60%, 0% 94%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bona+Nova&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>HRTech & InsuranceTech</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gradientSec">
       

        <section class="">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left_side col-6">

                        <button type="button" class="tryUpBtn text-white font-weight-bold btn btn-primary mr-5 pr-3 pl-3"><h5>Try For Free Now!</h5></button>
                        <h1 class="text-capitalize text-white pt-4" style="font-family: 'Bona Nova', serif; letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 52px;">Set your business up with modern payrolls, benefits, and HR</h1>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color: rgba(235, 215, 240, 0.308); filter: blur(0.3px);
                    -webkit-filter: blur(0.3px);">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: rgb(26, 71, 168);" type="button">Get Started</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <h5 class="text-secondary">Our plans were built to fit your unique needs. Streamline, onboarding, benefits, payroll, PTO, and more with our simple intutive paltform.</h5>


                    </div>


      

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>


    </div>













</body>

</html>
```

The text is not displaying over clip pathed background.
Thank you

Comment: You can not clip an element, and then expect content of the element to still show outside the clipping area. If you want to apply this effect to the background only - then you need to apply it to a different element (probably _positioned_ behind the content), one that does not contain the content you still want to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the clip-path is clipping the whole element whereas you want it to clip only the background.

One way round this is to put the background onto a before pseudo element and clip that then the clipping wont affect the actual element.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.signUpBtn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(138, 147, 153, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid rgba(80, 110, 133, 0.75);
}

.signUpBtn {
    font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgba(183, 190, 196, 0.75);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(141, 159, 173, 0.75);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: transparent;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.tryUpBtn {
    font-family: Raleway-SemiBold;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    color: rgba(183, 190, 196, 0.75);
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(141, 159, 173, 0.75);
    border-radius: 40px;
    background: rgba(194, 194, 193, 0.308);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    margin-top: 70px;
}

.tryUpBtn:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(138, 147, 153, 0.75);
    border: 2px solid rgba(80, 110, 133, 0.75);
}

.gradientSec {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.gradientSec::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(57deg, rgb(245, 31, 209), rgb(49, 47, 199));
    clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 60%, 0% 94%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bona+Nova&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>HRTech & InsuranceTech</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="gradientSec">
       

        <section class="">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="left_side col-6">

                        <button type="button" class="tryUpBtn text-white font-weight-bold btn btn-primary mr-5 pr-3 pl-3"><h5>Try For Free Now!</h5></button>
                        <h1 class="text-capitalize text-white pt-4" style="font-family: 'Bona Nova', serif; letter-spacing: 2px; font-size: 52px;">Set your business up with modern payrolls, benefits, and HR</h1>
                        <div class="input-group ">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" style="background-color: rgba(235, 215, 240, 0.308); filter: blur(0.3px);
                    -webkit-filter: blur(0.3px);">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: rgb(26, 71, 168);" type="button">Get Started</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <h5 class="text-secondary">Our plans were built to fit your unique needs. Streamline, onboarding, benefits, payroll, PTO, and more with our simple intutive paltform.</h5>


                    </div>


      

                </div>
            </div>


        </section>


    </div>













</body>

</html>
```